# Can't Get Subcategory in Top Menu (Nop Root Theme 3.40) in NopCommerce

Tags: drop-down-menu, nopcommerce

Pleased Help

In Default theme get all category and sub category perfectly but in NopRoot theme there was a problem.

Like
Default Theme:
In TopMenu 1:Computer
            2nd cat : Desktop
                   3rd subcat      Desktop>Pc
                   3rd subcat      Desktop>Mac

```
                    2nd cat: Laptop
                    subcat    Laptop>Acer                 
                    subcat    Laptop>Dell
```

but in NopRoot Theme: 
                      1:Computer
                        2nd cat : Desktop
                   3rd subcat      Desktop>Pc

```
                    subcat    Laptop>Acer                 
                    subcat    Laptop>Dell
```

Cant get these cat or subcat:
                      subcat      Desktop>Mac

```
                    2nd cat: Laptop
```

these all are in Drop menu !!!

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you want to verify for each category in question from the category admin panel :

1. Verify every category has "Published" checked.
2. Verify every category has "Include In Top Menu" checked.
3. Verify every sub-category has a "Parent Category" selected.

For troubleshooting purposes, make sure users can select themes, and post a link to your store.

Answer (score 0):

Please increase "Number of subcategory levels in top menu: " settings from  Admin>Configurations>Settings>[Catalog Settings](http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/Setting/Catalog)